# CSS animation looks wrong/broken in some places on iOS devices only?

Tags: html, css, ios, animation, shopify

I am using a flip animation for a 'sale' badge, and the animation runs fine on desktop and in the mobile preview, but on my iPhone it works in some places, but in others it breaks. I have had 2 people who use Android phones that they do not see the issue either- so I believe it is a safari/iOS problem?

My website is: http://RamenGlow.com (shopify website)

If you scroll down to the "Top Android Cases" section of the homepage, this is where the issue is seen. From what I can tell, the issue only occurs when 2 products have the 'sale' badge and are next to each other.

I created a gif that shows the issue:
[issue-preview-gif](https://gyazo.com/7123d6a93a85991d187d9d0c353e0646)

The animation code is below:

```
animation: 5s anim-flipX ease infinite;
```

```
@keyframes anim-flipX {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateX(720deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(720deg);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Changing the position to absolute and making the z-index of the badge to a high z value fixed my issue. Not sure why, but it worked!

```
position: absolute;
z-index: 20;
```

Answer (score 1):

Some CSS properties are supported with vendor-specific syntax
so you need to use always these syntaxes to make cross-browser compatibility
`-webkit-css-property-name` for apple devices
`-moz-css-property-name` for some mozilla devices

Read more about vendor prefixes (here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix)

```
@keyframes anim-flipX {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(90deg);
    -o-transform:rotateX(90deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateX(720deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(720deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(720deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(720deg);
    -o-transform:rotateX(720deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(720deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(720deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(720deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(720deg);
    -o-transform:rotateX(720deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: tried this and it did not work. starting to think that it isn't the animation itself that is causing the issue. maybe something within the parent div, but it works sometimes and other times it doesn't so im at a loss.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariVisualEffectsProgGuide/AnimatingWithKeyframes/AnimatingWithKeyframes.html